# Can you please give a name to this type action by kids?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I asked my son to write few sentences; instead he tried to do naughty things like below. What do I call this type of action by kids in English?

[image]

Comment: maybe _scribbling_?

Comment: Are you asking about the scribbles or about his disobedience?

Comment: These definitely look like scribbles rather than [doodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doodle).

Answer (score 1):

*[scribble](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scribble)*:

> to cover with meaningless writing or marks:
> to write or draw in a hasty or careless way
> to make meaningless marks, scrolls, lines, etc., with a pencil, pen, or the like.

(Can be used as a noun or a verb)

Comment: Super, Got it clearly. Thanks Anglicist